# Gitlab Test Coverage Parsing Branches only

Tags: regex, gitlab, code-coverage, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to implement a regex that will output the **Code Coverage** only for **Branches** after running the `dotnet test` command by using the **Gitlab CI** *Test coverage parsing* but I'm a little bit stuck.

Regex is kind of hard for me, and I don't understand why this command isn't working properly `^\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\s*lines`

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to debug is to use a service like https://regexr.com.

I have put your regex in https://regexr.com/49pjk with an text input example, and you can see:

- what is or is not matched by your regex
- how your regex is structured

With that, you should be able to debug it.